# Android: Activity.onDestroy() restarts service

Tags: android, android-service, ondestroy

I've got an app that runs in the background, using a service. But when onDestroy is called in the main activity, the service gets reseted, calls onCreate and onStart over again. How can i prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to look at the value the service returns from its onStartCommand method. The default value is START_STICKY which will restart the service after it is destroyed. Take a look at the [onStartCommand documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) for more details: